# Single or multiple bazel WORKSPACE should be used for monolithic repo?

Tags: cmake, bazel, monolithic

We put all products and libraries in one monolithic git repository. Its layout looks like this:

```
- FooProduct
- BarProduct
- BazLibrary
- 3rd_party
 |- fftw
 |- msgpack
 |- zlib
```

At current, we are using *CMake* to control the build. As *CMake* has separated config, generate and build phase, it would take extremely long time to run if you generate all things together. To avoid this, we give top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for each part, and referring peer projects by up-level `add_subirectory` calls. For example:

```
# FooProduct/CMakeLists.txt
project(FooProduct)
add_subdirectory(../BazLibrary sibling/BazLibrary)
add_subdirectory(../3rd_party/zlib sibling/3rd_party/zlib)
......
```

Now we are evaluating *Bazel*, and I immediately got the question: should I only place one single `WORKSPACE` at top dir of the git repo?

```
- WORKSPACE
- FooProduct
- BarProduct
- BazLibrary
- 3rd_party
 |- fftw
 |- msgpack
 |- zlib
```

Or put many `WORKSPACE` files in each product/library and referring each other using `local_repository` rule?

```
- FooProduct
 |- WORKSPACE
- BarProduct
 |- WORKSPACE
- BazLibrary
 |- WORKSPACE
- 3rd_party
 |- fftw
   |- WORKSPACE
 |- msgpack
   |- WORKSPACE
 |- zlib
   |- WORKSPACE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single workspace or source/build tree by definition only has one (top-level) `WORKSPACE`. In theory you could place `WORKSPACE` branches of your tree, but one obvious source of confusion would be, you could not reach project targets when running bazel from directories where another `WORKSPACE` is along the path between `cwd` and project root. While you would not really be gaining anything in return.

If you wanted to distribute your configuration across multiple directories (or even submodules), you can add Starlark (`.bzl`) files with macros ("functions") defining corresponding repository rule targets (external dependencies) anywhere in your tree (such as `//3rd_party/...`) and load and execute corresponding corresponding definitions in your (project) `WORKSPACE` file.

But that would be more of an organizational matter (e.g. different people/groups maintaining different dependencies; or just keeping files small), effectively it works (is ultimately evaluated) just like having one big `WORKSPACE` file.

If the external dependency is referred to as a source and `BUILD` description. It really does not matter whether it was pulled from entirely different repo or sits in the same tree. It needs to be rebuild, but also gets cached, either way.